# Is it appropriate to use HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError in Production?

Tags: java

We have been struggling to diagnose the cause of an OutOfMemoryError we experienced on one of our production servers. Our attempts to reproduce the issue in soak tests have so far failed, and we are considering enabling `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` on our production servers, so that if it does happen again, at least we'll have some data.

Is it wise to enable this setting on production servers?

Comment: Depends on how critical the service is.

Comment: @Peter Critical. We're losing money any time the service is down.

Comment: Well not sure what else to tell you. It'd be better if you had a staging server in place.

Comment: We do have a staging server. And the service is load balanced, so if there is an outage, then it quickly fails over to the other leg.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look in [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/clopts001.html):

> **B.1.2 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError Option**
>
> The `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` command-line option tells the
>   HotSpot VM to generate a heap dump when an allocation from the Java
>   heap or the permanent generation cannot be satisfied. There is no
>   overhead in running with this option, and so **it can be useful for
>   production systems** where `OutOfMemoryError` takes a long time to
>   surface.
>
> You can also specify this option at runtime with the MBeans tab in the
>   jconsole utility.
>
> The heap dump is in `HPROF` binary format, and so it can be analyzed
>   using any tools that can import this format. For example, the jhat
>   tool can be used to do rudimentary analysis of the dump.

`-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` flag does not introduce performance or security problems in run time. The flag is checked only after `OutOfMemoryError` has happened.

You can specify the actual path to which the file is saved using the corresponding `-XX:HeapDumpPath` flag. (Regardless of where the file is saved, make sure the filesystem and/or the Java process has the necessary permission configuration to be able to write there.)

Comment: What's the source of the quote?

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/clopts.html

Comment: Would it be wise to use "-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError" after that as well? To make sure the JVM exits after the OoM error? Or would this somehow conflict with each other? I want a dump and after that that the jvm exits.